# How to filter a list for multiple startswith criteria?

Tags: c#

If I filter a list for multiple criteria I can do this like this:

```
string[] criteria = { "a1", "b1" };
var res = reslist.Where(x => criteria.Contains(x.book)).ToList();
```

Now I would like to do sth like this:

```
string[] criteria = { "a", "b" };
var res = reslist.Where(x => criteria.ContainsStartsWith(x.book)).ToList();
```

Obviously this doesnt exists. How can I check through a criteria list with startswith values?

Comment: So do want `Contains` **OR** `StartWith()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Any` extension method  .

```
var res = reslist.Where(x => criteria.Any(s=>s.StartsWith(x.book)).ToList();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around: `x.book.StartsWith(s)`?

Comment: I dont think this works. is there  sth wrong with you using x twice?

Comment: I think criteria contains `book`, not sure though. Only @nic can provide some example.

Comment: @nik I don't get it, could you elaborate the question?

Comment: you fixed it by changing x to s within your any statement

Answer (score 0):

Minor add to Hari's answer

Use below

```
var res = reslist.Where(x => criteria.Any(s=>s.StartsWith(x.book) || criteria.Contains(x.book)).ToList();
```